# How to ensure Dart Polymer element is ready before calling JavaScript function that uses it?

Tags: javascript, dart, dart-polymer

I have a `<div>` within a template of a Polymer dart component, which is used by the JavaScript library that is loaded by the component.
As soon as the page is loaded, from the dart script for the Polymer component, I need to call a JavaScript function passing it an object created in the dart side.
However, I get the error: 
`Invalid DIV id; could not get element with id: divForJS`

**html for the Polymer element**

```html
<script src="mylibrary.js"></script>

<polymer-element name="ele-one">
    <template>
        <div id="divForJS"></div>
    </template>
</polymer-element>
```

**dart code to go with the Polymer element**

```dart
var dartObj;
timeConsumingOp()
  .then((result) {
   dartObj = result;
   })
  .then((_){
   var jsObj = new JsObject.jsify(dartObj.toMap());
   context.callMethod('myJSFunction', [jsObj]);
  });
```

I have tried placing this code in `attached()` before and after the call to `super.attached()`, `created()`or in `ready()` but with similar results.

How do I ensure that the JavaScript function only gets called after the time consuming dart operation is complete and the div for it is ready?

Comment: I suspect the issues is something different than than a not ready element. Maybe the script has problems with the shadow DOM.

Comment: I agree, if the js library is looking for an element with the id `divForJS` in the main document then it won't find this div, because its inside a shadow root. If you can modify how its querying for the element then you could use a shadow piercing query selector, like `html /deep/ #divForJS`.